# SL4: Root element is missing

Tags: xml, silverlight-4.0

I know this has been asked elsewhere, but none of the questions or answers helped.
I open an  xml file in my SL 4 app:

```
StreamResouceInfo sri =  Application.GetResourceStream(new System.Uri("z.xml", UriKind.Relative));
if (null != sri)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(sri.Stream);
}
```

"Root element is missing" exception.

The xml:
   Hmm, can't seem to post the xml...  It is well-formed and valid, with a single root node and all tags closed.
Thanks for any hints...

Let's try it w/o the angle brackets:

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"
Root
    Collection name="Fonts"
        Value Lucida /Value
        Value Arial /Value
   /Collection
/Root
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this very issue.  I ended up just first putting the received stream into a XmlReader and then that into the XDocument.Load.

Your code would be

```
StreamResouceInfo sri =  Application.GetResourceStream(new System.Uri("z.xml", UriKind.Relative));
if (null != sri)
{
    XmlReader rdr = new XmlReader.Create(sri.Stream);
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(rdr);
}
```

In my case i was using the WebClient.DownloadStringAsync call so it was a little different

```
void getCacheData_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        StringReader stream = new StringReader(e.Result);
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
        XDocument doc = new XDocument.Load(reader);
    }
}
```